# Visual Studio Build Configuration Name does not show reflect correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, environment-variables

I have 2 solution Configurations 'Prod' and 'Staging'. They have respective Project configurations 'Prod' and 'Staging'.

While publishing I am checking environment variable $('Configuration'). If I pushing the code with Prod profile it works perfectly but when I change solution configuration from dropdown to Staging, the value of $('Configuration') remains prod. Why is it so?

Thanks